# In Keras fit_generator() if you have a max_q_size greater than 1 do you need to have multiple workers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

In Keras, when using `fit_generator()`, you can specify a `max_q_siz`e, which basically pre-fetches generator results in the background to save lag.  It would seem for this to work efficiently you'd need to have multiple worker processes (at least one to train, one to pre-fetch). Filling a queue serially with a single process then pulling it out doesn't seem to add much benefit, the overhead might even result in worse performance.

From the docs:

> **max_q_size:** maximum size for the generator queue
>
> **nb_worker:** maximum number of processes to spin up
>
> **pickle_safe:** if True, use process based threading. Note that because this implementation relies on multiprocessing, you should not pass non non picklable arguments to the generator as they can't be passed easily to children processes.

Do you need to explicitly set `nb_worker` to 2 or greater (the default is 1) or is there already at least one extra worker filling the queue as your model trains to get benefit of a generator queue greater than 1?

Also, if you use more than one worker, do you need to set `pickle_safe` to `True`?